# How to conver mqtt's payload data to kafka string type

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt, apache-kafka-connect

Now I'm trying to connect from mqtt messages to kafka (actually spark streaming in kafka)

I used this connecter https://github.com/evokly/kafka-connect-mqtt

And Spark-2.1.0, Kafka - 0.10.1.1

Spark streaming output such like this

```
({"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"mqtt"},{"schema":{"type":"bytes","optional":false},"payload":"MTIzMTIz"})
```

and producer code

```
object mqttProducer {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val brokerUrl = "tcp://ip"
val topic = "mqtt"
val msg = "123123"

var client: MqttClient = null

// Creating new persistence for mqtt client
val persistence = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence("/tmp")

try {
  // mqtt client with specific url and client id
  client = new MqttClient(brokerUrl, MqttClient.generateClientId, persistence)

  client.connect()

  val msgTopic = client.getTopic(topic)
  val message = new MqttMessage(msg.getBytes("utf-8"))

  while (true) {
    msgTopic.publish(message)
    println("Publishing Data, Topic : %s, Message : %s".format(msgTopic.getName, message))
    Thread.sleep(1000)
  }
}

catch {
  case e: MqttException => println("Exception Caught: " + e)
}

finally {
  client.disconnect()
}
```

and spark-streaming kafka consumer code

```
package hb.test1
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent

object test2 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("app")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))    


val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> 
  "servers ip",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)
val topics = Array("mqtt-kafka")
  val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)

val testStream = stream.map(x => (x.key, x.value))


testStream.print()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

How could I get String not byte?
please help guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That payload "MTIzMTIz" is the string "123123" just base64 encoded. If you want to just take the MQTT payload and send it to Kafka without base64 encoding you should use a ByteArrayConverter. In my config for the same mqtt connector I set the value converter like so:

"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter"

The above ByteArrayConverter comes with the Confluent Enterprise distribution but there are other open source Kafka Connect ByteArrayConverters such as the one included with the qubole/streamx kafka-connect-s3 connector.

https://github.com/qubole/streamx/blob/8b9d43008d9901b8e6020404f137944ed97522e2/src/main/java/com/qubole/streamx/ByteArrayConverter.java

There is KIP-128 to add a standard ByteArrayConverter to the Kafka Connect framework

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-128%3A+Add+ByteArrayConverter+for+Kafka+Connect

UPDATE: Kafka 0.11 is now released and ships with a ByteArrayConverter. Configure `"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter"` and you should get the raw mqtt payload without Base64 encoding.